# Can I have an Apache Server on Pi 3 if it's working as a WiFi AP

Tags: wifi, apache-httpd

I want to create a webserver local-network accessible but without router.  The idea is to connect a device (phone, PC) to the Raspberry over WiFi, and see the webpage on the Apache Server.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes there should not be a problem having the Pi run apache and be the access point as the Pi will act as a device on its own access point allowing the apache server to seem as if it is running though a router.

Comment: So if I want to connect using another device (phone) to the webpage in the raspberry, there should be no problem, right?

Comment: That is correct, please click the checkmark to the left of my answer to mark it as correct if it has helped you

Answer (score 0):

Complicated multipart question.  So let's break it down.

First, of course you can run a web server on your Rpi.  Whatever else it is doing with its networking doesn't affect that part.

Then, you talk about adding a generic device.  Your examples of a PC and a phone are dramatically different.

There are other posts on this web site that talk about making a Rpi media server.  I strongly suggest you do more research before posting a question like this.  Spend some time in the archives and you will likely find your answer.

Cheers.